# Naming Local Network IPs

Tags: networking, ip, naming

is there a way for accessing local network adresses with names instead of ips?

For example, in my businness im using 192.168.1.105:8081 to enter my CRM, also 192.168.1.105:8082 to enter another app and 192.168.1.105:8083 to enter another.

It would be cool to put only in the adress bar "crm" or "another app" instead of the numbers and ports.

I imagine something like "localhost"

Is this possible? Im using a linksys router.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For local name conversions, you must set up a local DNS server in your LAN. Also if you want the LAN machines to connect to the Internet, you must set up DNS proxy.

Comment: DNS can't do anything about the port numbers, though.